# Printing SubStrings, Python

Tags: python, string, substring

I am writing a function that is to return the words of a string between the firstWord and secondWord that are given by the user.

```
def returnWordsBetween(firstWord, secondWord, inputString):
    start = inputString.find(firstWord)
    end = inputString.find(secondWord)
    inputString =(start, end) 
    print inputString 

    firstWord = '<data>'
    secondWord = '</data>'
    inputString = 'fooz bizz <data> 31.25 funnel </data> fuzz'
```

Does this look to work? I am not getting anything to print out and no error codes, not sure what is up

Comment: indent last 3 line outwards(<--)..

Answer (score 3):

You may use regex.

```
print re.search(firstWord+r'(.*?)'+secondWord, inputString).group(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
inputString[start + len(firstWord):end]
```

For example:

```
firstWord = '<data>'
secondWord = '</data>'
inputString = 'fooz bizz <data> 31.25 funnel </data> fuzz'
start = inputString.find(firstWord)
end = inputString.find(secondWord)
print inputString[start + len(firstWord):end]
```

Result:

```
 31.25 funnel
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slicing` concept of `python` here. And can be solved in one line

```
inputString[ ( inputString.find(firstWord) + len(firstWord) ) : inputString.find(secondWord)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring package by "pip install substring". This package is multi-operational and would be able to solve your problem.